# Parameters Note Being Sent in SOAP request from PHP

Tags: php, soap

I am running the following code:

```
<?php

// $wsdl = "http://www.restfulwebservices.net/wcf/StockQuoteService.svc?wsdl";
$wsdl = "http://clublinq.com/marylandlive/clublinq.svc?singleWSDL";

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array(
                        "trace"=>1,
                        "exceptions"=>0));

//    var_dump($client->__getFunctions()); 
//    var_dump($client->__getTypes()); 

//  $stock = "IBM";

// $parameters= array("request"=>$stock);
$parameters= array('KeyID'=>"1B3BFE04-78AF-4B84-967E-C32BA0B30FB0",'PlayerID'=>2588);
var_dump($parameters);
$value = $client->GetCustomerInfo(array('request' => array($parameters)));

// $value = $client->GetCustomerInfo(array('request' =>"1B3BFE04-78AF-4B84-967E-C32BA0B30FB0" ));
 var_dump($value);
 print "<pre>\n";
 print "<br />\n Request : ".htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequest());
 print "<br />\n Response: ".htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastResponse());
 print "</pre>";
?>
```

Using Wireshark, I have determined that my request is being sent with the parameters as null.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Are u sure $value = $client->GetCustomerInfo(array('request' => array($parameters)));
line is corryect, you are making array of an array

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
$parameters= array('KeyID'=>"1B3BFE04-78AF-4B84-967E-C32BA0B30FB0",'PlayerID'=>2588);

$value = $client->GetCustomerInfo( $parameters );
```

Don't forget to mark it correct if it worked

Answer (score 0):

Here is another of sending soap request

```
$parameters= array('KeyID'=>"1B3BFE04-78AF-4B84-967E-C32BA0B30FB0",'PlayerID'=>2588);

$value = $client->__soapCall('GetCustomerInfo', array('parameters' => $parameters));
```

Comment: I did not try this one, because of the answer above.  However, I believe this works as well.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked.

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient("http://clublinq.com/marylandlive/clublinq.svc?singleWSDL",array(
                        "trace"=>1,
                        "exceptions"=>0)
);

$req->KeyID = "1B3BFE04-78AF-4B84-967E-C32BA0B30FB0";
$req->PlayerID="2588";
$parameters->request = $req;
$obj = $client->GetCustomerInfo($parameters);
print "<pre>\n";
print "<br />\n Request : ".htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequest());
print "<br />\n Response: ".htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastResponse());
print "</pre>";

>
```